# How to use my custom font in Mathjax in android webview

Tags: android, fonts, webview, mathjax

How to add my own font to mathjax and use it in webview in android. Thanks

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of the other question, as the OP is asking how to change the MathJax font, which is quite different than how to change the default font for the webview.  It is really a MathJax question, not a webview one.  The answer is you really can't unless you want to do a lot of work.  See [the MathJax-dev forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mathjax-dev/erUIt9iHPzw) or some details about this.